# drupal 304 Not Modified не найден

Tags: drupal, seo, header

Здравствуйте. Сайт на Drupal 7 на виртуальном хостинге. При тестировании https://last-modified.com/ru/if-modified-since.html . Результат - тест провален (Last-Modified найден! 304 Not Modified не найден!) Смотрю файл bootstrap.inc - вроде как есть условия для отдачи этого заголовка....

Подскажите как настроить? (любой вариант кроме патча ядра, возможно есть готовые модули)

Comment: какой вебсервер? nginx может обрубать этот заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

Если используется nginx, то по умолчанию он обрубает этот заголовок. Надо включить модуль SSI (Server Side Includes), по умолчанию он отключен.

```
server{
  ...
  ssi on;
  ssi_last_modified on;
  ...
}
```

Больше информации:
http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi_last_modified

Comment: написал свой модуль, который формирует этот заголовок - работает нормально, т.е. проблема не в этом, но за информацию спасибо